# Wordpress Theme is not adaptable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

**(Wordpress)** The menu overrides any page, hiding the price and other elements see:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEvte.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyqMy.png)

Theme Name: SHOPPER RESPONSIVE WOOCOMMERCE

My website: iporao.com.br

SOLVED: Within the header.php has a class called header spacing, I put a margin-top of 100px and solved the problem. Thanks for all

Comment: SHOPPER RESPONSIVE WOOCOMMERCE – FREE https://dessign.net/shopper-responsive-woocommerce-free/

Answer (score 0):

OMG, menu has position absolute and fixed to top. If you want push content below menu you can add spaced div with specific height.
Anyway without header code with menu, I not able to suggest where you should add that spacer.

Usually i setting whole header as position absolute and after header adding something like this `<div class="header-spacer"></div>` then in javascritp adding function

```
function spacerHeight() {
    var headerHeight = $('.header').outerHeight();
    $('.header-spacer').height(headerHeight);
}
```

and firing the function on document ready and after resize.

In your theme spacer name is `.header_spacing`, you can try to search someting with name **header spacing** in that theme settings or simply edit https://iporao.com.br/wp-content/themes/ShopperWooTheme/js/scripts.js file by adding

```
spacerHeight();

$( window ).resize(function() {
    spacerHeight();
});

function spacerHeight() {
    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight();
    $('.header_spacing').height(headerHeight);
}
```

after `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: I did not change the theme, downloaded it and just installed normally, you can's a look at my website? www.iporao.com.br      Thanks

Comment: Updated Answer with solution.